# How to center a login box horizontally and place right at bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

This is the html.

```
<template name="atTemplate">
    <div class="card card-container">
        <div class="at-form">
            ...... <!-- embedded form using {{> atForm}} -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Initally without any css, the embedded form is stuck at **top left** of the screen .

So when this is the css below, the login box is **stuck at the bottom left** of screen. Changing `position: fixed` doesnt make a difference.

```
.card-container.card {    
  width: 262px;          
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

changing `position: absolute` the box shifts to **horizontal middle, but is now right at the top of the screen** instead.

I have tried many other suggestions such as removing and swapping in the below. However the login box now goes to **top and horizontally middle** of the screen.

```
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

I also see some solutions on nested css..like outer div being absolute and inner being relative or something but I do not know if it can be helpful here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fnfb95v/

Comment: great solution @JaredFarrish I was playing with `position: fixed` but could not pull it like you did

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for the good answer! Saved me some hours of playing with the permutations!

Answer (score 2):

You are so close. Just add `left:0` and `right:0` but DON'T add top position:

```
.card-container.card {    
  width: 262px;          
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/7fnfb95v/1/)**